# Add a negative point pls

Tags: javascript

Could you add a -1 for me? When I post something somebody add always -1 so I want to collect a negative score.

Comment: At this point the best thing you can do is to just pick one and learn from it. Once you get the hang of it you'll understand the animation space better and will gradually be able to understand the potential pros and cons of different animation techniques so that you can figure out what's the best tool to use in which situation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Google Developers website:

> - Use CSS animations for simpler “one-shot” transitions, like toggling UI element states.
> - Use JavaScript animations when you want to have advanced effects like bouncing, > stop, pause, rewind or slow-down.

More information [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/look-and-feel/animations/css-vs-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

In general: CSS deals with presentation and JavaScript deals with behaviour.

A common approach is to build your animations using CSS3. (This also gives you hardware acceleration in most modern browsers.) Then use JavaScript to add the interactivity that trigger the animations (if any.)

Answer (score 0):

I use JavaScript plus jQuery for animations. CSS is (don't judge) in my opinion excellent only for styling the animations. However, CSS3 made a huge improvement, and future versions might make CSS the perfect tool for animation. So, if you already know CSS, I say learn basic JavaScript and learn how to animate with jQuery, and style your animation with CSS.

Answer (score -1):

Why not learn both? If you looking at developing a cross browser animations why not create all your CSS3 for the later browsers and create a javascript/jQuery alternative for browser that don't support CSS3.